# Docker Toolbox: Could not locate Gemfile since Host directory is not mounted to Home directory

Tags: ruby, docker

I have Docker Toolbox installed on my local machine and I'm trying to run Ruby commands to perform database migrations.  I am using the following docker commands within the **Docker Toolbox Quickstart Terminal Command Line**:

```
docker-compose run app /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake db:migrate
docker-compose run app bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
docker-compose run app /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake db:seed
```

However, after these commands are called, I get the following error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Within Docker Toolbox, I am within my project's directory as I run these commands (C:\project).

After doing some research, it appears that I need to mount my **Host** directory somewhere inside my **Home** directory.

So I tried using the following Docker Mount commands:

```
docker run --mount /var/www/docker_example/config/containers/app.sh:/usr/local/bin

docker run --mount /var/www/docker_example/config/containers/app.sh:/c/project
```

Both of these commands are giving me the following error:

```
invalid argument "/var/www/docker_example/config/containers/app.sh:/usr/local/bin" for --mount: invalid field '/var/www/docker_example/config/containers/app.sh:/usr/local/bin' must be a key=value pair 
See 'docker run --help'
```

Here is what I have in my docker-compose.yml file:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
app:
    build: .
    command: /var/www/docker_example/config/containers/app.sh
    volumes:
      - C:\project:/var/www/docker_example
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "9312"
    links:
     - db
    tty: true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are running this from a Windows Git Bash or Docker QuickStart Terminal?

Comment: Docker QuickStart Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are running on windows. You need a shared folder between your Docker machine and the Host machine.

[image: Shared folder]

Above is on my mac. You can see my `/Users` is shared as `/Users` inside the VM. Which means when I do

```
docker run -v ~/test:/test ...
```

It will share `/Users/tarun.lalwani/test` inside the VM to `/test` inside the container. Now since `/Users` inside the VM is shared to my host this would work perfectly. But if I do

```
docker run -v /test:/test ...
```

Then even if I have `/test` on my mac it won't be shared. Because the host mount path is dependent on the Docker host server.

So in your case you should check which folder is shared and then to what path is it shared. Assuming `C:\` is shared at `/c` Then you would use below to get your files inside the VM

```
docker run -v /c/Project:/var/www/html ..
```

Comment: By using the docker commands, how would I configure which folder is shared and to what path it is shared?  I actually do want to share C:\ with `/c` when I run these commands.

Comment: You will have to manually do that by opening VirtualBox, going to the Docker-machine VM, Right click ->Settings->Shared Folders and then add the folders you want to share

Comment: Ok so I went into VirtualBox and changed the shared folders so that the settings are `Folder Path: C:\project` and `Folder Name: project`.  When I run the original commands `docker-compose run app /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake db:migrate
docker-compose run app bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
docker-compose run app /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake db:seed ` I'm still getting the same `Could not locate Gemfile` error.

Comment: The reason is that the folder gets shared in different folder inside VM. Project will be shared in `/media/sf_project`. See this article https://www.howtogeek.com/187703/how-to-access-folders-on-your-host-machine-from-an-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/